# pyspark - TypeError: count() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am concatenating a bunch of columns and counting them.I can't count on an alias?

```
df.select(F.col("_c21"),F.concat(F.col("id1"),F.lit("|"),F.col("id2"),F.lit("|"),F.col("id3"),F.lit("|"),F.col("id4").alias("ids")))
df.repartition(col("_c21"])).count("ids").over(Window.partitionBy("_c21"))
```

Data looks like this

```
+--------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|                _c21|concat(id1, |, id2, |, id3, |, id4 AS `ids`)|
+--------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|roBMSlo...|                                  US|WA|98115|Centu...|
|3Vzlfim...|                                  FR|56|56130|SFR.....|
|rgBdftS...|                                  CA|NB|E1A|Bell Ca...|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `F.count`, not the `count` method of dataframe (which counts total number of rows). Also no need to repartition because the window will do the partitioning anyway. And you also misplaced a bracket for the alias.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.select(
    F.col("_c21"),
    F.concat(
        F.col("id1"),F.lit("|"),F.col("id2"),F.lit("|"),F.col("id3"),F.lit("|"),F.col("id4")
    ).alias("ids")    # misplaced close bracket here
)

df2 = df1.select(F.count("ids").over(Window.partitionBy("_c21")))

# or if you want an additional column, use 
df2 = df1.withColumn("count_id", F.count("ids").over(Window.partitionBy("_c21")))
```

In fact, `concat_ws` is more appropriate:

```
df1 = df.select(
    F.col("_c21"),
    F.concat_ws(
        "|",
        F.col("id1"), F.col("id2"), F.col("id3"), F.col("id4")
    ).alias("ids")
)
```

Comment: Cannot resolve column name "count" among (_c21, count(ids) OVER (PARTITION BY _c21 unspecifiedframe$()));

Comment: Pretty sure that error is because there was no alias applied on the count function.

Comment: @VK_217 apologies, there was a typo in the last line of the first code snippet - it should be `df1.select`, not `df.select`. Could you please try again?

Comment: Ended up using group by df.repartition(F.col("_cid")).groupby("_c21","ids").count(). Thanks @mck, appreciate your suggestion

Comment: cheers @VK_217 , next time when you post questions on SO, it would be great to include a sample dataframe and an expected output dataframe - that would help us reach the answer more quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

Go with spark-sql. It improves readability, portability, and also easy to debug.

Sample input:

```
df = spark.sql(""" with t1 (
 select  'roBMSlo' c1,   'US' c2,   'WA' c3,   '98115' c4,    'Centuy' c5    union all
 select  '3Vzlfim' c1,   'FR' c2,   '56' c3,   '56130' c4,   'SFR' c5    union all
 select  'rgBdftS' c1,   'CA'  c2,  'NB' c3,   'E1A' c4,   'Bell Ca'  c5    
  )  select   c1  _c21  ,   c2  id1   ,   c3 id2  ,   c4  id3   ,   c5 id4      from t1
""")
df.show(truncate=False)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

+-------+---+---+-----+-------+
|_c21   |id1|id2|id3  |id4    |
+-------+---+---+-----+-------+
|roBMSlo|US |WA |98115|Centuy |
|3Vzlfim|FR |56 |56130|SFR    |
|rgBdftS|CA |NB |E1A  |Bell Ca|
+-------+---+---+-----+-------+

spark.sql("""
select _c21, ids, count(ids) over(partition by _c21) cw from (
select _c21, concat(id1,id2,id3,id4) ids  from df )
""").show()

+-------+---------------+---+
|   _c21|            ids| cw|
+-------+---------------+---+
|roBMSlo|USWA98115Centuy|  1|
|3Vzlfim|   FR5656130SFR|  1|
|rgBdftS| CANBE1ABell Ca|  1|
+-------+---------------+---+
```

If you want to join with a separator,

```
spark.sql("""
select _c21, ids, count(ids) over(partition by _c21) cw from (
select _c21, concat_ws("|",id1,id2,id3,id4) ids  from df )
""").show()
```